# Add colours to issues in Jira

Tags: jira

I would like to add colours in the issues in Jira. Also, I would like to see the priority arrow and type issue. Please find attached my current view and something with colours similar to what I would like to see.

[My desire view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jarEu.png)

[My current view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTIMH.png)

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

According to the screenshot, it seems that you are trying to configure a board of a [next-gen project](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/working-with-agility-boards-945104895.html). It is a simplified type of project which has rather limited functionality.

If you create a classic project instead, you'll be able to configure the board according to your needs. Card colors, layouts and other settings will be available from the Board Settings (top left corner of the board).